# How to use new custom field of DISPLAY SUITE in node.tpl.php (Drupal 7)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm right now working on one of the **drupal 7** project, which is basically based on Social networking like facebook.

Where we are including one of the module **Heartbeat**, in which we have done some customization and create one custom field from the **Display Suite** module. i have made this custom field and which is working good with Heartbeat module, but now we need required to display this custom field in all the other entity like **node**, **comments**, **user profile** etc..
I tried hard to do it but can't get success on. Can anyone give me hint how to use those custom **display suite fields** in **node.tpl.php** file ??

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Chandresh.

Comment: Damn. _More_ social networking sites.

Comment: not to worry...its just for couples only.. :)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: I have implemented module and also created one custom field from display suite, but i want to knw how to call this custom field into node.tpl.php page.??

Answer (score 0):

In your node.tpl you have to use following code, for example field name : field_header

```
 <!-- For Showing only custom field's Value Use below code -->
 <h2 class="title"><?php print $node->field_header['und']['0']['value'];?></h2>

 <!-- ========================= OR  ========================= -->

 <!-- For Showing custom field Use below code , which shows custom field's value and title-->
 <h2 class="title"><?php print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_header'));  ?></h2>

 <!-- ========================= OR  ========================= -->

 <h2 class="title"><?php print render($content['field_header']); ?></h2>
```